# Is there a way to rollback and exit a psql script on error?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a psql script that looks like this:

```
-- first set of statements
begin
sql statement;
sql statement;
sql statement;
exception
    when others then
    rollback
    write some output
    (here I want to exit the entire script and not continue on to the next set of statements)
end
/
-- another set of statements
begin
sql statement;
sql statement;
sql statement;
exception
    when others then
    rollback
    write some output
    (here I want to exit the entire script and not continue)
end
/
... and so on
```

Is it possible to exit the script and stop processing the rest of the script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put the following lines at the top of your file:

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
```

... and make sure you have a `RAISE;` at the end of your exception handlers.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to use raise_application_error when I want to halt execution and pass back a custom error code/message to the calling script:

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0480__PL-SQL-Programming/UsingRAISEAPPLICATIONERROR.htm

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... PL/SQL does have [GOTO](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/04_struc.htm) so you could jump to a label you place right at the end of the script.
eg:

```
GOTO the_end;
[rest of script here]
<<the_end>>
```